# SQL Server XML Declare Namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, xml-namespaces

I would like to have a few namespaces available by default when running an XQuery in SQL Server 2005, is this possible?

For example, I would like to do the following:

```
select * from TableWithXML
where
FieldWithXML.exist(
declare namespace nsp="http://www.example.com/exampleNamespace";
nsp:root/nsp:childnode) = 1
```

Without having to redeclare the namespace each time, so that SQL will recognize nsp without me including the prolog each time.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xml` and `xsi` namespaces are the only pre-defined namespaces that you do not have to declare yourself.  All other namespaces must be explicitally declared in every query.

There are two ways to declare namespaces:

1. via the `declare` statement inside the XQuery.
2. via the WITH XMLNAMESPACES clause on the TSQL statement.